# How to start and stop the same loop by the keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I want to make an macro clicker for games, but I dont know how to start and stop clicking loop by the same key on keyboard. Here is where I am:

```
def start_pvp_clicking():
    bind_pvp_key = entry1.get()
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.08
    while True:
        counter = 0
        if keyboard.is_pressed(bind_pvp_key):
             while counter == 0:
                print("clicking")
                if keyboard.is_pressed(bind_pvp_key):
                    while True:
                        print("not clicking")
                        break
```

When I press a key, loop is starting but I cant stop it and run again by the same key.

Answer (score 0):

The `counter` won't be updated after each time in the loop. It will remain `0` forever so the program will run forever.

Just update the counter to `counter + 1` to prevent infinity loop and change (`while counter == 0`) because that loop will stop after the counter is bigger than `0`, and you have 3 `while` loops and the last one sucks, there is no need to add the last loop, in the first loop call (`while True`) it will run forever because `True` will remain `True` forever.

I recommended adding a parameter called `gameTicks = 0.02`, then just temporarily stopping functioning each `gameTicks (0.02)`. If you did what I said, the program should work well.

Comment: can you represent it with code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while True:
    key_togle = 0
    if keyboard.is_pressed(bind_pvp_key):
        key_togle = 1
        while key_togle:
            print('Doing stuff')
            if keyboard.is_pressed(bind_pvp_key):
                key_togle = 0

    print('Not doing stuff')
```

Explanation:
You need to manage how to get in and out of a loop, so basically add a variable for breaking a inner loop, and a condition to change the value of the variable.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Ok, its working well but how to stop clicking in "Not doing stuff" if "doing stuff" = pyautogui.click() ???

Comment: Idk much about this lib, try to breakdown your problems in the question

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
key_togle = 0
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(bind_pvp_key):
        key_togle ^= 1
    if key_togle:
        print('do something')
```

Comment: Ok, but now, how to stop clicking mouse? if "do something" = pyautogui.click()

Comment: if key_togle: is true, you do what you want to do in the loop, but only one step or a few steps. for example, if your loop is moving a character around, you take the input from the player for the moving direction, move one step in the specified direction.

Answer (score 0):

I viewed your post a week ago and I had the same doubt. Now my problem is resolved, I hope it does yours as well.

```py
# Importing libraries
import time
import keyboard

key_toggle = False

def DoSomething(): # Function starts
    global key_toggle # To call the global variable
    key_toggle = not key_toggle # This works as an ON/OFF switch

    # The following if statement will always execute, if key_toggle is truthy.
    if key_toggle:        
        print("\nBot is ON") # Optional
        # The following sleep is important. 0.4s is the lowest value that works for me.
        time.sleep(0.5)

        # The loop won't stop unless you press the 'Q' key.
        while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
            print("\nLooping")
            # Your code here

    else:
        print("\nBot is OFF")
        time.sleep(0.5) # Function ends


keyboard.add_hotkey('Q', DoSomething) # The DoSomething() function will start with a press of 'Q'.
print("Press Q to toggle")
keyboard.wait() # The wait() function awaits a certain key to be pressed.
```